Is there a way to rename an external table in Azure Synapse Analytics?
I am trying to figure out how to rename a table in Azure Synapse Analytics. I've seen documentation online for RENAME OBJECT Table TO Table1; but I am not sure this works for external tables. I haven't seen any documentation online for how to do this with external tables. Is this truly impossible?
I have tried both RENAME OBJECT Table TO Table1; and exec sp_rename 'Table', 'Table1' but the first seems to not work for external tables and the second is not supported in Synapse Analytics.
